# Omit \headmark in table of contents

Tags: koma-script, pagestyle

I changed the chapterpagestyle to scrheadings to have the page numbers on the first page of a new chapter, but for the table of contents I do not want to have the headmark (in this case the chapter title ("contents") on the first page of the table of contents (same is true for list of figures and list of tables).

How can I omit the headmark for this specific pages?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,open=right,headinclude,footinclude]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\ihead{\headmark}
\automark*{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Test 2}
    \section{Test 2}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your MWE `\headmark` is empty on chapters first page, too. So maybe you should use the default setting of `\chapterpagestyle`, ie. page style `plain`. Add option `plainheadsepline` to get the rule below the header on `plain` pages, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\headmark` is empty on the first page of each normal chapter in your MWE (using `open=right`), because `\chapter` sets the left mark and cleans up the right mark. Therefore the first right mark on an odd chapter page is empty.

Note that `\automark*{chapter}\automark*[section]{}` or `\automark{chapter}\automark*[section]{}` does the same as `\automark[section]{chapter}`.

Table of contents puts `\contentsname` in both marks `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` at the same time. Therefore `\headmark` is not empty on the first page of ToC.

So I suggest to remove the redefinition of `\chapterpagestyle` and to adjust the content of page style `plain` to your needs. Then page style `plain` is used on all first pages of chapters including ToC, LoF and LoT.

Maybe you want:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=right,headinclude,footinclude]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[headsepline,
  plainheadsepline,% <- added
  automark% <- added
  ]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}% <- changed

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Test 2}
\section{Test 2}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Explanations:

1. The first page of each chapter uses the page style which is saved in `\chapterpagestyle`. This is page style `plain` by default. So removing the redefinition of `\chapterpagestyle` the example uses `plain` on the first page of a new chapter.
2. Option `plainheadsepline` adds the rule below the header on pages with style `plain`, but only if option `headsepline` is set, too.
3. Option `automark` activates running header entries. It uses the section level as right mark and the chapter level als left mark. So it does the same as `\automark[section]{chapter}`.
4. `\clearpairofpagestyles` removes the default content of page header and footer for both page style `scrheadings` and page style plain (alias of `plain.scrheadings`)
5. `\ihead{\headmark}` adds `\headmark` to the inner header of page style `scrheadings`. In twosided documents `\headmark` will be `\rightmark` on odd pages and `\leftmark` on even pages.
6. `\ohead*{\pagemark}` is a short version of `\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` and adds  the formatted page number to the outer header of both page styles `plain` (alias of `plain.scrheadings`) and `scrheadings`.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much.

Just for my understanding: with your MWE

1) The first page of each chapter still uses the plain pagestyle.

2) With plainheadsepline these pages get the headsepline.

3) The starred ohead adds the pagemark to these pages.

But what does the automark in the package options do and why don't I need to declare where to put the chapter and sections in the header? Is this so because it is the KOMA standard for Automark?

Comment: See my updated answer.